# How to make letscrypt work with cloudflare?

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I have my site running my server, letscrypt and was working fine. I can see the secure or encrypted padlock sign next to my browser tab whenever one visit my site. I then subscribed to cloudlfare free account and enable the full(strict) option for clouldflare ssl. my site ssl padlock stopped showing and now shows the info icon. when i expand and view the crt, there is a valid certificate from cloudflare, but the browser doesn't recognise my site as secured anymore. please how to i make my site secured again, use the letscrypt cert or mix the two ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear the browser's cache.

I had the problem same with you. I resolved my problem by clearing the cache.